# Creating extrarow for Django queryset

Tags: django, model

My model Table

```
col_1  col_2 col_3
##################
 1       a     3 
 2       b     5
 3       c     6
```

I did in view.py

```
results = Item.all()

for result in results
    total=+ result.col_3
```

I have total=14

How to do same through model method total()?

I mean: `results.total()` will return 14

Comment: I am not sure totally understand. Can you show your model ? 
you may add a properly method to the model that can solve it

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's fairly easy if you use aggregate method provided in django ORM. Also I want to note that it's faster than python for loop.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

queryset = Item.objects.all() # you can filter queryset if needed
result = queryset.aggregate(Sum("col_3"))
print(result.get("col_3__sum")) # will return the sum value
```

hope it helps, also please take a look at [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum)

**NOTE (on performance)**
the question is: "how aggregate is faster than using the way in the question?"

first of all let's make things clear, what happens when you write

```
Item.objects.all()
```

at this time database connection is not opened and no query is performed ([see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)). based on the doc when you are using for loop, that's the time when queryset is evaluated.

on the other hand when using aggregate, the db is hit only once and calculations are performed on the db side (see this [post](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/django-faster-to-aggregate), which is old but generally make a point).

I hope this clears your doubts

Comment: Faster is my target. Actualy im looking for faster and low cost method. How it will faster when i need double query: first for data, and second or agregate?

Comment: ok, let's think: while you are using for loop you are also fetching data (actually not fetching, just creating query, see the docs...). and then performing for loop (in for loop real data fetch is performed).

on the other hand, using aggregate, the operations are performed directly in the SQL which is faster than fetching all the data (with all the fields not needed) and then looping on it.

hope, I cleared things, for you

Comment: Ok. I know that query set not querying.

Comment: This is correct for only agregating without fetching. But usualy, after i did Item.objects.all() next step wil be fetching (in tepmlate) anyway. I just need to exclude extra query to SQL and summing together fetching.

Comment: I don't understand your point, what you are trying to achieve? Please take a look at your question and then at my answer and tell me if there is something wrong. If you are in need of something other, please modify the question or just create new one!